# move the "shopping options" feature from sidebar to my category page in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

My problem is that I am using a theme in magento and using the `1-column` layout of the template.

I want to show the "`shopping options`" feature in my category page as filter options.

Currently I have the shopping option in my `2-cloumn` layout in the right sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uttam ,you can the layer navigation on top of category after breadcrumbs.Please check my code.Please goto catalog.xml for your template app>design>frontend>Mypakacage>My template>layout>

```
 <catalog_category_default translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
        <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">

        ...
```

For anchor category

```
  <catalog_category_layered translate="label">
            <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
            <reference name="content">
             <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
                <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
......
```

Comment: i am fairly new to magento. can you please tell me if where i am supposed to integrate this code.??